# GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync returns null

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

The problem of this Windows UWP code:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(new Guid("00001520-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd124")));
GattDeviceService m_service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);
```

is that `m_service` is always `null`. The BLE device which contains gatt service with `00001520-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd124` UUID is paired (the device is visible in device manager with no exlamation mark).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

To insert following code to Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Capabilities>
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:heartRate" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 1):

R. Wang's can be  the correct answer, but is very hard and maybe impossible to change the `Package.appxmanifest` correctly by hand.
In visual Studio in solution explorer right-click on `Package.appxmanifest` and select open.
Click capabilities and thick Bluetooth and save Packagemanifest (<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).
If this is not the solution for your problem, than we need more of your relevant code to help.